# Adding multiple coupon codes to one shopping cart price rule

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I have a list of 10 coupon codes and I would like to add them to one shopping cart price rule.

I wonder if this is possible.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without the help of MYSQL. The way I've done this is to first create the rule, then auto generate the amount of codes you need. Then I would go into the database and replace the codes Magento generated with the codes I needed them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible under "Catalog price rule" find where it says "Auto Generate" check that option and then goto "Manage Coupon codes", you'll be able to generate it here:

[image]

[image: Generate Coupon Qty here]